# ExpressJS API router.get external function

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to hack together two separate examples, I have them working separately but I can't wrap my head around how to combine them. I have now wasted multiple hours getting something so basic to work.

I have ExpressJS running an API. The test message works.

```
// test route to make sure everything is working (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api)
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'This is a test message' });    
});
```

I want to show the output of the the below, instead of the message: This is a test message

```
serverClient.call('version', {}, function (err, res) {
    console.log('Server Version: %j', res.version);
});
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction with a clear how to option or show me the code?

Comment: `res.json({ message: 'Server Version: ' + res.version });`

Comment: It provides the server version in the console.log but not in the message.

Comment: var router = express.Router();     
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

ServerClient.call('version', {}, function (err, res) {
    console.log('Server Version: %j', res.version);
});

res.json({ message: 'Server Version: ' + res.version });

});

Answer (score 1):

Just move that code into your route handler. Example:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  serverClient.call('version', {}, function (err, result) {
    if (err)
      return res.json({ error: err });
    res.json({ version: result.version });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `res` variables have different names, otherwise they will collide

```
// test route to make sure everything is working (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api)
router.get('/', function(req, res1) {
    res1.json({ message: 'This is a test message' });    
    serverClient.call('version', {}, function (err, res2) {
        console.log('Server Version: %j', res2.version);
    });
});
```